# Is it worth upgrading to SSD or just to buy new?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, ssd

I'm deciding whether or not to upgrade to SSD's in my Late 2011 15" MacBook Pro 2.4 GHz i7, or if its finally starting to come to that time where I need to just fork out and buy a new MacBook.

I'm not sure whether upgrading to SSD will solve my problems for long, as my laptop is taking around 20 - 30 minutes from a cold start to just open applications... I have tried everything, even a complete wipe of the HHD and a fresh install of the OS.

Thoughts?

Comment: What shows in a verbose boot as taking a long time - Separately my first gues on speed would be your HD try booting off an external disk

Comment: I also have the same Late 2011 2.4 GHz model. it starts within 2 minutes and apps open within few seconds. I did not even change the 750 GB HDD. So may be something wrong with your computer. Anyway, with an SSD the Mac will be much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a Late 2011 MacBook Pro too. After upgrading to Yosemite last year, I was thinking on buying a new Mac, since performance was very bad. 
Every kind of application was incredibly slow to open, even working with more than one app at time was impossible. Also just opening a simple PDF took a lot of time.

At the end, I decided to install a SSD on my Mac. A new world. Now everything works properly and my laptop seems to be reborn. I also updated to El Capitan and performance is even better.

So I advise you to buy a SSD, before giving up with your Mac. I have a Samsung SSD SATA 250 GB and I am very satisfied. You can spend less that 120-130 $ and you will have a completely new experience.

Comment: Yes! My daughter has a 2009 MacBook. She complained it was running slowly. I offered a deal - I'll upgrade to SSD, if you are still unhappy, I will buy you a new laptop, Air I guessed. She said it was like a new computer. New one will be in 2 years when she's off to college. We will have gotten 8 good years from that MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

Any Intel i# equipped computer no matter the age should not be slow. If it is slow you have either a hardware or software issue. I could never recommend replacing any Intel i# equipped computer unless it was for a better video card or needing an insane amount of RAM. If it is taking that long to boot after a fresh install my first guess would be hard drive issues. Have you tried using Disk Utility to see if it comes up with anything? And do you have El Capitan installed and up to date? To sum it up though, a simple SSD will bring new life into any computer and is much cheaper, I would recommend buying one to install in your MacBook, worst case scenario you at least have a new SSD for a new MacBook.